# Azure ADF how to ensure that the same files that are copied, are also deleted?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

Using Azure ADF and currently my setup is as follows:

Event based triggerd on a input BLOB on file upload. File upload triggers a copy activity to  output BLOB, and this action is followed by a delete operation on the input BLOB. The input BLOB can take 1 or many files at once (not sure how often the file is scanned/how quickly the event triggers the pipeline). Reading up on the delete function documentation it says:

```
Make sure you are not deleting files that are being written at the same time.
```

Would my current setup delete files that are being written?

Event based trigger on file upload >> Write from input Blob to Output Blob >> Delete input Blob

I've made an alternative solution which does a get metadata activity based on event in the beginning of the pipeline, and then does a for loop which deletes the files at the end, not sure if this is necessary though. Would my original solution suffice in an unlikely event where I'm receiving files every 15seconds or so?

Also while I'm at it, in a get metadata activity how can I get the actual path to the file, not just the file name?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Delete Active](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/delete-activity) says:

- Make sure you are not deleting files that are being written at the
  same time.

Your settings are:

- Event based trigger on file upload >> Write from input Blob to Output
  Blob >> Delete input Blob

Only after the active `Write from input Blob to Output Blob` finished(the deleting files are not being written),  then the `Delete input Blob` can works.

Your questions: Would my current setup delete files that are being written?

So did you test these steps? You must test by yourself and you will get the answer.

Please notice:

**Delete activity does not support deleting list of folders described by wildcard.**

Any other suggestions:

You don't need to using delete actives to delete the input blob after `Write from input Blob to Output Blob` finished.

You can learn from [Data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview), it's Source settings support delete the source file(input blob) after the copy active completed.
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I guess this same feature is not available in a normal pipeline. Btw, isn't dataflow a much more expensive alternative? Thats one of the reasons I'm contemplating on not using it, and using a for each loop instead in a normal pipeline (if thats the only alternative).

Comment: @Anton Yeah, this feature is only supported in data flow. About your alternative solution, you need to consider the file size, copy performance and so. It's difficult to answer if it's suffice. According my experience, I think for each loop is the only alternative. You still need to test many times and adjust your alternative solution to achieve some balance.

Comment: If Data flow is more expensive(not very much), but  it works well and saved more time for you, it's worthy. In the end, if my answer is helpful for you, hope you can vote up or mark it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I could not use Leon Yue [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59744622/1843853) because my source dataset was a sftp one, which is not supported by Azure dataflows.

To deal with this problem, I used the Filter by last modified of the dataset. I set the End Time to the time the pipeline has started.

[image: Filter by last modified End Time]

With this solution, only the files added to the source before the pipeline started will be consumed by both the copy and delete activities.